# Remove duplicates from list with objects based on an attribute of an object

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, attributes

So i have this Arraylist of objects,those objects have name and timestamp as attributes.I need a method that when it finds a duplicate name in the arraylist,it removes the object with the smaller timpestamp.It seem pretty easy in theory but i am really stuck.What i ve tried is this :

```
            for (int j=0; j<travellers.size(); j++){
                if ( (travellers.get(i).getName() ).equals( sorted_travellers.get(j).getName() ) ){
                    if (travellers.get(i).getTimestamp() < sorted_travellers.get(j).getTimestamp()){
                        sorted_travellers.remove(j);
                    }else if (travellers.get(i).getTimestamp() > sorted_travellers.get(j).getTimestamp()){
                        sorted_travellers.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using StreamEx - it can be done nice and easy:

```
    StreamEx.of(travelers)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Traveler::getName))
        .collapse((t1,t2) -> t1.getName().equals(t2.getName()),
            (t1,t2) -> {
                if(t1.getTimestamp().compareTo(t2.getTimestamp()) > 0){
                    return t1;
                }
                return t2;
            }).toList();
```

Another solution, which doesn't allocate any additional memory and has n*lgn time complexity could be:

```
    travelers.sort(Comparator.comparing(Traveler::getName)
        .thenComparing(Traveler::getTimestamp).reversed()
    );
    //Now list sorted in order when all items with the same name are near and highest timestamp is first

    Iterator<Traveler> iterator = travelers.iterator();
    

    Traveler current = null;
    Traveler next = null;

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        if (current == null) {
            current = iterator.next();
        } else {
            next = iterator.next();

            if (next.getName().equals(current.getName())) {
                iterator.remove();
            } else {
                current = next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
    List<Traveller> travellers = new ArrayList<>();
    travellers.add(new Traveller("test", 0L));
    travellers.add(new Traveller("test", 1L));
    
    Map<String, Traveller> latestTravellers = new HashMap<>();

    for (var traveller : travellers) {
        latestTravellers.merge(traveller.getName(), traveller,
                (existing, incoming) -> incoming.getTimestamp() > existing.getTimestamp() ? incoming : existing);
    }
    
    Collection<Traveller> updatedTravellers = latestTravellers.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Traveler> filter(List<Traveler> travelers) {
    List<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
    return travelers.stream()
            .sorted((t1, t2) -> -t1.timestamp.compareTo(t2.timestamp))
            .filter(t -> !found.contains(t.name))
            .peek(t -> found.add(t.name))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove duplicates, and keep only the record with the latest timestamp, you can do it like this:

```java
List<Traveller> travellers = ...

// Determine traveller objects to keep.
Map<String, Traveller> byName = new HashMap<>();
for (Traveller traveller : travellers) {
    byName.merge(traveller.getName(), traveller,
                 (a, b) -> a.getTimestamp() > b.getTimestamp() ? a : b);
}

// Remove traveller objects that shouldn't be kept.
// Use iterator to prevent ConcurrentModificationException.
for (Iterator<Traveller> iter = travellers.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Traveller traveller = iter.next();
    if (traveller != byName.get(traveller.getName()))
        iter.remove();
}
```